# Standard codes to identify email types (work, personal, etc.)

Tags: hl7, snomed-ct

I work for a health technology company and we use the HL7 and snomed standard codes to identify phone numbers, home addresses, races, ethnicities, etc. I have been looking to no avail for HL7 or snomed standardized codes to define user email types. Is there another standard with codes that identifies types of email?

Comment: You can at least differentiate personal and business email by putting them into the relevant PID field (Phone Number - Home PID/13) and (Phone Number - Business PID/14). Take care of the XTN component 4.

Comment: thanks that was great help and pointed me in the right direction

Comment: for future reference if anyone is having a similar problem refer to this site http://hl7-definition.caristix.com:9010/Default.aspx?version=HL7+v2.5.1&dataType=XTN

Comment: @wintoch, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  That site might not be available in the future.  In fact, it's not available today for me, since it runs on a non-standard port that is blocked from here.  Please take the relevant information, format it into an answer to your own question, and post it here as an Answer.  You'll build your reputation on the site in the process.

Answer (score 2):

In PID/13 and PID/14 you can set the second component (Telecommunication Use Code ) to **NET** meaning **Network (email) Address** and then add the **home eMail adress in PID/13/4** respective **business adress in PID/14/4**

Answer (score 1):

In the end we used the above Hl7v2 Conmunication standards to generate our own codes. Bellow are the tables we referenced.

XTN: Extended Telecommunication Number

SEQ    | LENGTH | DT | OPT | TBL # | NAME

XTN.1  | 199    | ST | B | PhoneNumber Telephone Number

XTN.2  | 3 | ID | O | 0201 | Telecommunication Use Code

XTN.3  | 8 | ID | O | 0202 | Telecommunication Equipment Type

XTN.4  | 199 | ST | O | Email Address

XTN.5  | 3 | NM | O | Country Code

XTN.6  | 5 | NM | O | Area/City Code

XTN.7  | 9 | NM | O | Local Number

XTN.8  | 5 | NM | O | Extension

XTN.9  | 199 | ST | O | Any Text

XTN.10 | 4 | ST O | Extension Prefix

XTN.11 | 6 | ST O | Speed Dial Code

XTN.12 | 199    ST  C | Unformatted Telephone Number

---

0201: Telecommunication use code

VALUE |     LABEL

PRN | Primary Residence Number

ORN | Other Residence Number

WPN | Work Number

VHN | Vacation Home Number

ASN | Answering Service Number

EMR | Emergency Number

NET | Network (email) Address

BPN | Beeper Number

---

0202: Telecommunication equipment type

VALUE |     LABEL

PH  | Telephone

FX  | Fax

MD  | Modem

CP  | Cellular Phone

BP  | Beeper

Internet    | Internet Address: Use Only If Telecommunication Use Code Is NET

X.400   | X.400 email address: Use Only If Telecommunication Use Code Is NET

TDD  | Telecommunications Device for the Deaf

TTY  | Teletypewriter